# How to remove EventListener from an element (like chrome does)

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

How can remove EventListener from an element using javascript? I want to approach the same thing as chrome when we click "remove listener", but there is a problem, there are no listeners neither on document nor on element, but how chrome find and remove them?
[image]

Comment: By literally doing that? You add event listeners with `addEventListener` and you remove those same listeners with `removeEventListener`. But you don't get to simply ask which listeners exist: your code needs to remember what got added, so that it can ask for it to be removed again.

Comment: Are you asking a dynamic version of the question? i.e. remove an unknown listener by discovering the currently registered listeners?

Answer (score 2):

You can assign an event listener by calling `target.addEventListener(type, handler)`

You can remove this by calling `target.removeEventListener(type, listener)`

Comment: You need the handler in the `removeEventListener` as well, it cannot just be the type. --Update; the edit above is now correct.

Comment: Yes I fixed that sorry

Answer (score 1):

Simple example:

```
const someElement = document.querySelector(".someClass");

// add event listener
someElement.addEventListener("click", () => {
  // log this on click event
  console.log("Event added");
});

// remove event listener
someElement.removeEventListener("click", () => {
  // log this when you remove event
  console.log("Event removed");
});
```